# Can I make this code cleaner in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, boolean, conditional-operator

```
var isFilterOn = false;

$('#toggle-filter-btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!isFilterOn){
            isFilterOn = true;
        }else{
            isFilterOn = false;
        }
 })
```

Suppose I have an above piece of code.

Now, I was hoping to make the part where I set the `isFilterOn` to true or false, more concise.

So I tried this,

```
var isFilterOn = false;

$('#toggle-filter-btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        isFilterOn == false ? isFilterOn = true : isFilterOn = false; 
 })
```

But I am suspecting there is a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code can be a bit clean in this way

```
var isFilterOn = false;

$('#toggle-filter-btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // your way
        isFilterOn == false ? isFilterOn = true : isFilterOn = false; 
        // little clean version
        isFilterOn = isFilterOn?false:true;
        // best option use revers boolean operator
        isFilterOn = !isFilterOn 
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the result of inverting the truthyness:

```
$('#toggle-filter-btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        isFilterOn = !isFilterOn;
});
```